# Cursor Not Showing When TextBox is Focused With Tab

Tags: wpf, textbox

When focusing a TextBox with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the cursor does not show. This does not change when typing. This problem is only resolved when the user clicks inside the TextBox.

Here is the code for my TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameField"
             Style="{StaticResource placeHolder}"
             Tag="Name" 
             FontFamily="Courier New"
             FontSize="48"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
             SelectionBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"
             BorderThickness="0"
             TextChanged="ChangeName"
             Height="49"
             KeyDown="UndoRedoKeyPress" />
```

I tried to resolve the error by adding `this.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;` to the Change Text Event, but it did not work.

**EDIT**: I have reproduced this glitch in a new project with two TextBoxes in an empty window with the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="placeHolder" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             x:Name="textSource" 
                             Background="Transparent"
                             Foreground="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"
                             CaretBrush="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"
                             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             SelectionBrush="{TemplateBinding SelectionBrush}"
                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                             Panel.ZIndex="2"
                             AcceptsReturn="{TemplateBinding AcceptsReturn}"
                             AcceptsTab="{TemplateBinding AcceptsTab}"
                             TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" />
                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}" Panel.ZIndex="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                             SelectionBrush="{TemplateBinding SelectionBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When clicking on the first TextBox and then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the second TextBox. The cursor will not be visible while typing.

Comment: Your issue cannot be reproduced based on the information you have provided. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your qustion to include a MCVE of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 I have updated my original post with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TextBox` style should include any child`TextBox` elements. Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="placeHolder" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}" />
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Panel.ZIndex="2"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Foreground="LightGray">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" 
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```